# Is there a difference between gluLookAt() and glFrustum()?

Tags: opengl

My instructor says they can be used interchangeably to affect the projection matrix. He argues that `gluLookAt()` is preferably used because of its 'relative simplicity due to its ability to define the viewing angle'. Is this true? I've seen code examples using both `gluLookAt()` and `glFrustum()` and I'm wondering why would the programmmer mix them.

Like in the cube.c example of the redbook appears:

```
void display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glLoadIdentity(); 

  gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  **//why isn't this a call to glFrustum?** 
  glScalef(1.0, 2.0, 1.0); 
  glutWireCube(1.0);
  glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{

  glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0); 
  //why isn't this a call a call to gluLookAt()? 
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: hum. gluLookAt and glFrustum set very different matrices (gluLookAt does _not_ typically get applied to the projection matrix). Are you sure your instructor was not talking about gluPerspective instead of gluLookAt ?

Comment: The main difference is that glFrustum is part of the core OpenGL library, and gluLookAt is part of a helper library which takes a different set of parameters and then calls glFrustum. It makes no difference to OpenGL which one you use; the choice is one of coding preference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `glFrustum` and `gluLookAt` perform simple matrix multiplication. Check the man pages for equations for those matrices:

[gluLookAt](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/gluLookAt/)

[glFrustum](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glFrustum/)

Both of those can be replaced by a `glMultMatrix*` call.

The most important difference is that `glFrustum` is used most of the time to establish a perspective projection matrix (used internally by `gluPerspective`), and `gluLookAt` is a convenience method for specifying model-view matrices (usually: implementing a camera).

Answer (score 2):

gluLookAt affects the ModelView matrix whereas, glFrustum/gluPerspective affect the Projection matrix. These are entirely two different matrices in the pipeline. gluLookAt is a utility method which is a combination of glRotate and glTranslate calls to move the "camera" to the appropriate point in space and point it to the desired location. Whereas, glFrustum/gluPerspective are methods which define a perspective viewing volume. Check out for more details in the OpenGL Red Book.

Comment: Hurm? These functions affect the matrix that's been set by glMatrixMode.